# Connecting to MS Access from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I found this code online, which connects from C# to an SQL server database.

I wish to do something similar, but I want to connect to an Access 2010 database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1.DAL
{
    public class PersonDAL
    {
        public string ConString = 
            "Data Source=SOURAV-PC\\SQL_INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public DataTable Read()
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConString;
            if (ConnectionState.Closed == con.State)
                con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Person",con);
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(rd);
                return dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public DataTable Read(Int16 Id)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConString;
            if (ConnectionState.Closed == con.State)
                con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Person where ID= "+ Id +"", con);
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(rd);
                return dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should I change my code to do that ?
For the example, let's assume that my access DB is in: C:\VisualStudioProject\Sample

Thank you!

Comment: `Connecting to MS Access from C#` and `I want to connect to an Access 2010 database` sounds and means different things. Have you tried to search for *connect access c#*? [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Use Connection string as:

   string connectionstring = Standard security
   Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
   Persist Security Info=False;
2. Use OLEDB instead of SQL

   OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);

Comment: I got an error when tried this: public string ConString = "Standard security Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Visual Studio Projects/HR/-----/---.accdb; Persist Security Info=False";  OleDbConnection AccessConn = new OleDbConnection(ConString); The error was: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property 'ConSrting'

Comment: I have just added an another answer to help you further. Please do change namespace as per your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PersonDAL
    {
        public string ConString =
           @"Standard security Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection con;
        DataTable dt;
        public PersonDAL()
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection();
            dt = new DataTable();
        }

        public DataTable Read()
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConString;
            if (ConnectionState.Closed == con.State)
                con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Person", con);
            try
            {
                OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(rd);
                return dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public DataTable Read(Int16 Id)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConString;
            if (ConnectionState.Closed == con.State)
                con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Person where ID= " + Id + "", con);
            try
            {
                OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(rd);
                return dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```